# change link with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, dialog

I am trying to change a link programmatically.

Example:

I want to call a dialog and change an image buttons url link based upon the call it gets.

so:

```
<a href="javascript:myHref('http://www.google.com')" onclick="$('.hiddendiv').dialog('open');" >  Edit Address </a>
```

the function myHref would change a link within the div (let's call it myAnchor) to http://www.google.com.

Thoughts on how to go about this?
 I've seen methods for changing a designated link, but not in this manner.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You can change an anchor's `href` with jQuery by doing `$(myAnchor).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/');`, but is there more to this question than that?

Comment: I think that will work, and then I can call the function from another link

Comment: but will that work inline like my example above?

Comment: We'd have to see the code for `myHref` and `dialog` to be able to tell you with any accuracy. Or at least, *I* would, because I'm still not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: myHref is a made up function - doesn't do anything. I was trying to get a function written called myhref to pass the value to another button. But in this case, it's just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code might be what you are looking for:

```
var linkattributes=document.getElementById("link-id").attributes;
linkattributes.getNamedItem("href").value = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: ah. But I need to change a different link, not the one calling the function.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `document.getElementById('link-id').href = 'http://www.google.com/';`?

Comment: will that work inline? example: `href="javascript:document.getElementById('link-id').href = 'http://www.google.com/';"`

Comment: Ah, didn't think that was a valid DOM attribute, but in that case it's better :)